# Azure cosmos DB physical partition unbalanced with no hot partition key indicated

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have this problem:
new physical partitions are being created for me and requests often occur on the same partition. I wonder how is this possible since I have no hot partition keys indicated?

[image]

[image]

My only partition key is an id composed as follows:

user id _ year _ travel number

I memorize the geographical positions of vehicles.

[image]

This obviously generates several 429.
I hope I was clear.

EDIT ----------------------------------------

I set up the log and investigate:

[image]

Is it possible that a json of 400kb produce a request write od 2900 RU/s ?
The document is this:

[image]

I don't understand why the result of console say a count of 4 when i have load only one document??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The graph shows you have a hot partition. You need to select a partition key with higher cardinality to more evenly spread writes across partitions and migrate your data into this new container. This can be best done using Change Feed to read from your existing container and write the data into your new container. When Change Feed has caught up you can change the connection string in your app and restart it to then write to the new container with very little downtime.

Comment: Hi @Mark, thanks for your response. How can i locate the hot partition key? Sorry but i can't understand how is it possible, because every value of partition key (genKey) have at max 100-150 documents sored in cosmos..

Comment: There are some tools to investigate?

Comment: Yes. There are diagnostic logs you will need to enable. More information on how to configure and query these can be found here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cosmosdb-monitor-resource-logs  Thanks

Comment: However, why i have a hot partion key? My PK have a wide range of values.. high cardinality!

Comment: You have a hot partition because one or a few of your partition key values is getting a lot of requests. To find out which ones those are you will need to use the diagnostic logs and query for them.

Comment: Thanks @Mark.. i try to investigate but i don't understand the result.. can you help me?